# Why do these two expressions produce the different value?

Tags: javascript

Why do these two expressions produce the different value in some environments?

```js
const i = 33;
console.log(i ** i === 33 ** 33) // false

const j = 44;
console.log(j ** j === 44 ** 44) // true
```

The expressions only evaluate to `false true` on certain environments, including Google Chrome.

Comment: It prints `true`, `true` in Firefox Nightly 65.0a1 (`i ** i` is `1.2911004008776101e+50`) and `false`, `true` in Node 11.0.0 (`i ** i` is `1.2911004008776101e+50`, `33 ** 33` is `1.2911004008776103e+50`).

Comment: Your testing is wrong - the snippet that you provided shows `true` `true`

Comment: @Slai I edited your question with that information

Comment: Further testing in Node: `new Uint8ClampedArray(new Float64Array([33 ** 33]).buffer)` contains `[89, 128, 115, 155, 205, 21, 86, 74]`; `new Uint8ClampedArray(new Float64Array([i ** i]).buffer)` contains `[88, 128, 115, 155, 205, 21, 86, 74]` (which it also contains in Firefox).

Comment: `Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => [i, eval(`${i} ** ${i}`) === i ** i]).filter(([i, eq]) => !eq).map(([i]) => i)` is the array for all numbers where the equality doesn’t hold (up to 99): On Node: `[29, 31, 33, 34, 39, 49, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 65, 66, 67, 72, 73, 74, 75, 78, 79, 80, 83, 85, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 95, 97, 98, 99]`. On Firefox: `[]`. `i ** i` seems to behave identically to `Math.pow(i, i)`.

Comment: this statement also returns false: `console.log(Math.pow(33, 33) === 33 ** 33)`

Comment: I used BigInt, that seems right.
`i = BigInt(33); console.log( i ** i === BigInt(33) ** BigInt(33));`

Comment: Hurray for Firefox.

Comment: Floating point equality should not be relied upon.  A common solution is subtract and abs > some varriance.

Comment: there is a small rounding error probably because `i ** i` is calculated at run-time and `33 ** 33` maybe evaluated directly at "compile" time. `i ** i === Math.pow(33, 33)` is true